# Is there a way to combine $(this) with :nth-child?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

I'm in the middle of an .each iteration and wanted to call out the 2nd or 3rd child for the each..but cant make it work.

```
alert($(this + ' :nth-child(2)').attr('id'));
```

My only option that I can think of is something terrible goofy like this:

```
 $(this).children(':first').next().attr('id', 'ddParam' + newCount);
 $(this).children(':first').next().next().attr('id', 'txt' + newCount);
 $(this).children(':first').next().next().next().attr('id'...
```

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).find(':nth-child(2)')`?

Comment: I hadnt, but now I have and it didnt produce any results.. Thanks though

Comment: my bad - haha... child #2 in my case has no ID (thus a blank return)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

What you need is [context](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery). With context, the selector will only look for elements that are the children of the context (in this case `this`).

```
$(':nth-child(2)', this).attr('id');
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LmeMn/)

This is basically the same as:

```
$(this).find(':nth-child(2)').attr('id');
```

If you only need the direct children, not every descendant, you should use `.children()`:

```
$(this).children(':nth-child(2)').attr('id');
```

Comment: alert($(':nth-child(1)', $(this)).attr('id'));  -- thanks, but this produces nothing for me... any thoughts?

Comment: @toddv Oh, I had a mistake, fixed. I added a jsFiddle to let you test this.

Comment: Whoops.. my child #2 had no id -- thus a blank popup --- sry.  THANKS FOR THE ANSWER!