# Selecting data out of the nth td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

I'm attempting to get the data("borgid") out of the following html:

```
<tr style="cursor:default;" class="odd">
    <td class=" ">1</td>
    <td class=" ">What was your favorite childhood pet's name?</td>
    <td data-borgid="1" class=" ">Generic Hospital Networks</td>
    <td class=" ">5173</td>
    <td style="text-align:right;" class=" "><input type="button" value="Remove" name="1" class="deleteMeCQ" style="cursor:pointer;"></td>
</tr>
```

I have tried both **$(':nth-child(2)', $(this)).data("borgid")** and **$tds.eq(2).data("borgid")**.  Both return "undefined".  Thanks in advance.

See also: [Is there a way to combine $(this) with :nth-child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983471/is-there-a-way-to-combine-this-with-nth-child)

```
var a = [];
$("#ChallengeQuestionsTable tbody tr").each(function () {

var $tds = $(this).children('td');

var questionid = '';
var question = '';
var borgid = '';

if ($tds.length == 5) {
    questionid = $tds.eq(0).html();
    question = $tds.eq(1).html();
    borgid = $(':nth-child(2)', $(this)).data("Borgid");

    a.push('{ "questionid" : "' + questionid + '", "question" : "' + question + '", "borgid" : "' + borgid + '" }');
}
});
```

Comment: You want to get the value? `1` (or whatever it might be)?

Comment: Tried `borgid = trs.eq(2).data("borgid");`?

Comment: This would work: `borgid = $(this).find('[data-borgid]').data('borgid');`  Out off topic but consider to use relevant variable name, here `trs` should be `tds` or even better `$tds`

Comment: `var trs = $(this).children('td');` >.<

Comment: borgid = $($tds.eq(2)).data("borgid");  Is what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get borgid, you can select by existing attribute:

```
borgid = $($(this).find("[data-borgid]").get(0)).attr("data-borgid");
```

Comment: This technically works, I think I'm looking for something more like this (to use your code): $($(this).find("[data-borgid]").get(0)).data("borgid");  I was hoping for a more elegant solution than find() but this works.  Thanks!

Comment: This solution got me closest to what I'm actually using in my code which is **borgid = $($tds.eq(2)).data("borgid");**

Comment: Great, just be careful of not changing the element's index if you are using that

Comment: Right.  Yours is definitely a more dynamic solution but that's not as important at the moment.  I was more concerned with a solution that is less of a load on the browser.  I know it's not much but is still less.  Thank!

Answer (score 0):

In general if you want to select the *nth* td you could go with

```
$("td:eq(1)")
```

e.g. to select the second td. 
If you want to iterate over all `<tr>` and its `<td>` and say, you want to select the 2nd one, you would do it as follows:

```
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function(){
    $(this).find("td:eq(1)").html("changed")
};
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twT7u/1/) to play with. And here is the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) of `:eq()`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work, if you grab the data by an attribute selector?

```
var borgid = $(this).find("td[data-borgid]").data("borgid");
```

It could also be beneficial to avoid ":nth-child", shall you change your HTML later.